# Testing tsx component with mocha - TypeScript, React and Mocha

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, mocha.js, babeljs

I have a component `abc.tsx` (which was previously `abc.js` before I started adding support for TS in my React project along with upgrading to Babel7). The component compiles fine on `npm start` and I am able to load it in the browser. However, when I run my test file `abc.spec.js` (using `Mocha 5.x`), the test fails with the error:

```
import React from 'react';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier...

// this error is shown to be in abc.tsx, whose first line is the import
```

Can I use a `*.spec.js` file to test `*.tsx` file? If yes, does this have to do with the configs I have? Despite having spent a couple of hours searching on the web, I am unable to find the right answer. So, I would really appreciate any help with this.

Here are my config files:

**webpack.config.js**

```
// all other stuff
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.tsx']
},
module: {
  rules: [
         
          {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                include: Conf.src.js_path,
                use: 'babel-loader'
          }
   ]
// all other stuff
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false ,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "es2015",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "mocha testSetupFile.js \"./src/**/*.spec.js\"" //
}
// testSetupFile.js has "require("@babel/register")" among other things
```

**babel.config.json**

```
// this does need some clean up for plugins section
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-spread", {"allowArrayLike" : true}
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {"regenerator": true}]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix `.js` and `.ts(x)` you will need to use something like `ts-node` and ensure that you have the `--allowJs` flag enabled in your `tsconfig.json`